# Setting values in a matrix according to values in another matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a correlation matrix (c.mat) and a matrix of p-values for each of these correlations in (p.mat).

Each coordinate in p.mat is the p-value for the correlation at that coordinate in c.mat.

I would like to set any correlations in c.mat with a p-value below a threshold (0.05) as NA.

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That seems to be a rather standard subsetting problem. Do you know how subsetting works in R? Try something along the lines of `your_matrix[your_index] <- NA`.

Comment: I did not know how subsetting worked in R. I'm very new to R and trying to learn on my feet as I'm trying to tackle a large dataset at work. I was unsure what the name was for what I was trying to do so I appologise for the simple question. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as coffeinjunky mentioned above, this can also be done with basic subsetting operations:

(@cory, I used some of your code)

```
set.seed(9)

c.mat <- matrix(rnorm(9, 10, 2), nrow=3)
p.mat <- matrix(rnorm(9, .2, .2), nrow=3)
c.mat[p.mat<0.05] <- NA

# inital c.mat
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 11.775768 10.364504  8.613336
[2,]  8.585017  9.466223 15.363980
[3,] 13.513986 11.852843 10.445049

# inital p.mat
          [,1]      [,2]        [,3]
[1,] 0.1274126 0.2142108  0.03211007
[2,] 0.4555141 0.1467923  0.18451039
[3,] 0.1062206 0.5690514 -0.32354111

# c.mat after threshold correction
          [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 11.775768 10.364504       NA
[2,]  8.585017  9.466223 15.36398
[3,] 13.513986 11.852843       NA
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `which` is what you are looking for. This assumes the same matrix size.

```
set.seed(9)
a <- matrix(rnorm(9, 10, 2), nrow=3)
b <- matrix(rnorm(9, .2, .2), nrow=3)
a[which(b<.05)] <- NA
```